# Compiling zip component for PHP 5.2.11 in MAMP PRO

Tags: php, zip, compilation, mamp

Helo

I installed MAMP PRO on my Macbook Pro (10.6) some time ago. Now I would like to use zip functions in php. I found that I must add zip.so to my extension folder and edited php.ini.

On my computer I have two different versions of PHP one in MAMP folder and other in user/lib which was pre-installed on my system.  Now I wish to compile my zip library for MAMP version.

I got zip sources for my version of PHP then in terminal called function 
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/phpize` so it uses mamp php version

`./configure`

`make`

then I moved compile `zip.so` to `extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613`.

When MAMP is launched it returns this error:

`[11-Apr-2010 16:33:27] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zip: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Can some body explain to me how to do this the right way.

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: I am new here should I move this question to serverfault ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `phpenmod zip`?

```
usage: phpenmod [ -v ALL|php_version ] \
                [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name \
                [ module_name_2 ]
```

You can list all your available modules with `ls /etc/php/*/mods-available`.